# Trying to covert long to ToDate format

Tags: apache-pig

My input is long "20190503143744" and wanted to convert to format "2019-09-06 11:46:22"

Trying below code:

```
A = LOAD 'stp_master_subscriber_profile' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader() as (mdn:chararray, imei:chararray, imsi:chararray, subscriber_id:long, manufacturer:chararray, model:chararray, update_time:long, scenario:chararray, vz_customer:chararray, commit_time:long);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ToString(ToDate((chararray)commit_time,'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as event_date_gmt:chararray;
```

Getting error:

```
ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias B. Backend error : org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing [POUserFunc (Name: POUserFunc(org.apache.pig.builtin.ToDate2ARGS)[datetime] - scope-15 Operator Key: scope-15) children: null at []]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "20190503143744" is malformed at "143744"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're specifying the format as `yyyyMMdd` but your original input is in `yyyyMMddHHmmss` format, so you get an error when Pig reaches `143744` instead of the end of your string. Try this:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ToString(ToDate((chararray)commit_time,'yyyyMMddHHmmss'),
    'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as event_date_gmt;
```

Comment: Just now I also figured out the same. Marked your answer as correct. Thanks!!